# Would you please explain me. What is the following R operation

Tags: r

```
dt_modAdstocked[, (all_media) := mediaAdstocked]
```

**Context**
https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Robyn/blob/main/R/R/model.R#L455

**Details**
I am new to R, reading the code and lost what this operation is doing, is it assignment? something else?

Comment: This is syntax of the R package `data.table`. Please look at documentation e.g. [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/:=)

Comment: Assignment by reference

Comment: Could not understand form doc yet, if you can add explanation as an answer, I would gladly accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntax used by the R package `data.table`. Refer to the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/:=).
Your pattern is of type `DT[i, (colvector) := val]` and it is to assign a value `val` to multiple columns `colvector` at the rows `ì`. Here is an example to assign greatness and fanciness to *all* rows (`DT[, (colvector) := val]`) of the iris flowers:

```r
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(iris)
data
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#>   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
#>   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
#>   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
#>   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#>   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
#>  ---                                                            
#> 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
#> 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#> 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#> 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#> 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
colvector <- c("is_fancy", "is_great")
data[, (colvector) := TRUE]
data
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species is_fancy
#>   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa     TRUE
#>   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa     TRUE
#>   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa     TRUE
#>   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa     TRUE
#>   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa     TRUE
#>  ---                                                                     
#> 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica     TRUE
#> 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica     TRUE
#> 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica     TRUE
#> 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica     TRUE
#> 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica     TRUE
#>      is_great
#>   1:     TRUE
#>   2:     TRUE
#>   3:     TRUE
#>   4:     TRUE
#>   5:     TRUE
#>  ---         
#> 146:     TRUE
#> 147:     TRUE
#> 148:     TRUE
#> 149:     TRUE
#> 150:     TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: what a great explanation, thank you so much!